# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'controls') in Nested Form of Angular Form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I'm new to angular. Working on creating nested form in angular where I'm facing difficulties for getting controls of some fields based on the JSON structure shown below where I'm facing difficulties in getting control assetsList -> description section

```
data = {
    headline: [
      {
        language: 'en',
        headlineText: 'example headline',
      },
    ],
    bodyText: [
      {
        language: 'en',
        bodyText: 'example bodytext',
      },
    ],
    location: {
      name: 'mkontheway',
      openingHours: [
        {
          day: 'Mon-frd',
          timing: '10.00PM-9AM',
        },
      ],
      address: {
        postCode: 'test',
        country: 'test',
      },
    },
    assetsList: [
      {
        description: [
          {
            language: 'En',
            text: 'Sports News Updated',
          },
        ],
        assetType: 'Description',
        assetLink: 'NewsLink',
        filePath: 'Not yet fill',
      },
    ],
  };
```

[image: Error in console]

I created a Stackblitz for the same please help me for solving this error

[StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fafufv?file=src/app/create-news/create-news.component.ts)

Comment: Have you considered that headlineFormData does not indeed have the property controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assetsListDescriptionFormData can **not** be a getter because you need indicate the "index" of the assetsList -you has a FormArray inside another FormArray- else a function that you pass an index

```
getAssetsListDescriptionFormData(index:number) {
    return <FormArray>this.assetsListFormData.at(index).get('description');
}
```

And use

```
<div formArrayName="description" style="position: relative;">
   <div *ngFor="let description of 
              getAssetsListDescriptionFormData(assetsListGroup).controls; 
              let assetsListDescriptionGroup=index">
        
      <div class="form-fields-wrapper" [formGroupName]="assetsListDescriptionGroup">
              ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```